# Value cannot be null mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get this error when clicking a button and here is the code for this button

{

```
        int i = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);

        int p = int.Parse((string)ViewState["PricePerCube"]); //error on this line
        string img = ViewState["Image"].ToString();

        string s2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        string s1 = Request.QueryString["TreeInCart"];




        SqlConnection a = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        a.Open();
        string cartCmd = "insert into FullCart(TreeInCart,QuantityCubed,User,Image,PricePerCube) values('" + s1 + "','" + i + "','" + s2 + "','" + img + "','" + p + "') ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cartCmd, a);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        a.Close();
```

Comment: When you step through the code in the debugger, what do you find?

Comment: check my edited question, that's the code that brings up the "value cannot be null" error and on debugging it shows a zero

Comment: when you are setting `ViewState["PricePerCube"]`?

Comment: Oh, "_it_ shows a zero". Vague enough. When you examine `ViewState["PricePerCube"]` what is the result? Tip: Once you get down to the SQL bit, prepare to meet [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). That will be a good time to study up on _SQL injection_.

Comment: You should not be vandalizing you own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do proper null checks. Especially then when you are working with or depending on structures and values you haven't created.

So this line `int i = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);` will throw **NullReferenceException** when your control *TextBox1* is removed from aspx page.

I don't know the expectations of that what you are creating but what you could do is this:

```
var viewstateValue = ViewState["Sumthing"] ?? "0";
int p = int.Parse(viewstateValue);
```

This at least makes sure that you'll get a **Zero** which you then can use for your T-SQL Statement.

And for heaven's sake use SQL Parameters if you don't want to be vunerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to paste the stack trace. It looks like int.Parse() is throwing
an ArgumentNullException which means that

```
ViewState["PricePerCube"].ToString() //returns null.
```

You can put a breakpoint and check the above value when debugging.

Can I also suggest you try using TryParse like this so you can pinpoint what is happening:

```
int price;
string priceString = ViewState["PricePerCube"].ToString();

if (int.TryParse(priceString , out price))
{
    // code if parse succeeded
}else{
    // code if parse DID NOT succeed
}
```

Also what is ViewState["PricePerCube"] returning? That should be the first thing to check, if it is 0 (int) then string cast will throw.

Comment: check my edited question, that's the code that brings up the "value cannot be null" error and on debugging it shows a zero

Comment: I strongly suspect (string)ViewState["PricePerCube"] is null. You should add a check for it ...

Comment: I did as you suggested and the parse does not succeed.. so what do i do now?

Comment: Next step would be to check the value of ViewState["PricePerCube"] and by the way you have the answer to the question of why you got that exception in the first place

Comment: Don't do this `ViewState["PricePerCube"].ToString()`!! It throws a **NullReferenceException** if `ViewState["PricePerCube"]`is null.